# Utilizing classes in Python

Tags: python, class

I understand classes are used for attribute references and for instantiation, but what are some examples of meaningful or useful ways to utilize classes in Python?

Comment: The Python standard library has literally hundreds of examples...

Comment: There are literally gazillion of example on internet demonstrating practical use of classes.

Answer (score 1):

Classes are useful almost everywhere.  If I were to make a poker game, I'd define the cards, the deck, the hand, as a class.  If I were to make an RPG, the player would be a class, the inventory manager would be a class.  The inventory objects would be classes, the monsters would be classes.

A class is useful when you need to bundle data into individual objects.  Like if you've got an RPG, and you've got a couple of monsters, you need the monsters to have bundled data.  They all have a health pool, an attack value, and a bunch of methods that handle their AI.  But they're also individual.  Hitting one monster with your sword, for example, should not hurt ALL the monsters in the game at once.  Each monster is its own object and the data within the monster object is unique to that monster.  Hurting `monster1.health` does not hurt `monster2.health.`

Any time where you need multiple data sets and functions tied to individual objects, you could use a class.